# Complex interactive expression

Tags: emacs, elisp

That's what I've been using:

```
  (interactive "sEnterh the name of the figure (e.g. markov-chain.png): 
sCaption: ")
```

that's what I want to use:

```
  (interactive (list (read-file-name "Image file: " (if (file-exists-p "_static")
                                                        "_static"
                                                      default-directory
                                                      )))
"sCaption: ")
```

How can this be done?

In words -- one can mix interactive types in a single string:

```
  (interactive "r
sEnter char to use: 
sNumbering style used (d for digit, l for letter, r for Roman digits): 
sShould I dobule line breaks? (RET for yes) ")
```

but how can I combine interactive type, in my example is "s" with an elisp code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, if you use Lisp code to build a list of arguments to `interactive`, your code needs to handle all the arguments, and you will not have access to the convenience prompting facilities of `interactive`. So your first example would turn into

```
(interactive
  (list
    (read-file-name "Image file: " (if (file-exists-p "_static")
                                       "_static"
                                      default-directory) )
    (read-string "Caption: ") ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh I solved it without interactive types:

```
(defun rst-bk-numfigs ()
  (interactive) 
  (let (Fig Caption)
    (setq Fig (file-name-nondirectory 
               (car (list (read-file-name "Image file: "
                                     (if (file-exists-p "_static") ;; actually I need dir-p
                                         "_static"
                                       default-directory
                                       ))))))
    (setq Caption (read-from-minibuffer "Caption: "))))
```

Probably integration of interactive types with elisp code is not possible.

Comment: `read-from-minibuffer` is a function meant for internal use.  Use `read-string` instead.

Comment: Please note this is inferior to @tripleee's solution that uses interactive forms properly.  It cannot be called as a function (non-interactively that is).

Comment: @event_jr: I agree. The example of using elisp in inteactive opens up new scripting capabilities.

Comment: @Stefan: ok. Can't remember where I saw `read-from-minibuffer`.